# Django passing variables into string

Tags: python, django, string, image, variables

I'm trying to pass:

```
>img src="{% static '/static_dirs/images/itcg/01_{{ card_id }}.jpg' %}" alt="{{ card_id }}">
```

to load image with file name 01_xx.jpg, but the result is just xx without image. Basically what happens is that {{ card_id }} works in alt but I can't load the image. I have tried to change 01_{{ card_id }}.jpg into 01_01.jpg and it works, so the static files can load properly but apparently 01_{{ card_id }}.jpg is not working as intended. I also tried to changing one of my image name from 01_01.jpg into 01.jpg and do the following:

```
>img src="{% static '/static_dirs/images/itcg/{{card_id}}.jpg' %}" alt="{{ card_id }}">
```

The image still not loading, so I guess the problem is not in "01_" part either. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{{ .. }}` embedded within a `{% ... %}` doesn't look good.
Write like this:

```
img src="{% static '/static_dirs/images/itcg' %}/{{ card_id }}.jpg" alt="{{ card_id }}">
```

That is,
this will get the correct base url for the static image (the directory),
and then you simply append the rest of the image file name.